# inner join not responding properly in prepared statement in php

Tags: php, mysqli

[image]

i have two **tables** users and **post**

```
function get_user_history($email){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT p.video_url, p.comments, p.post_date, p.views FROM  `post` as p INNER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = p.user_id WHERE u.email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}

$result = get_user_history("ssntpl.com@gmail.com");
```

it should return only two rows with ***post_id 15 and 16*** but it is returning all the rows in post table. if i use a simple select query then it is working totally fine. but not working correct whn i use join query.
i'm not able to debug it. kindly provide me the correct solution

Comment: My comment is not related with answer but there must be some unique constraint in your table, why are you inserting duplicate entries, it may give you trouble in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong parameter type `i` for numbers. Your Mail address is a string, so you have to use `s` (corresponding variable has type string).

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
```

> types: 
>   A string that contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables:

Type specification chars

```
Char    Description
i   corresponding variable has type integer
d   corresponding variable has type double
s   corresponding variable has type string
b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Well there are a lot of sites, I prefer simple http://php.net/manual/

Comment: thank you so much for solving my doubt. i'm new to object oriented programming in PHP. can you please suggest me good website like www.w3school.com to learn OOP in PHP. you help is really appreciated